# SMS Receiving and Sending in Flutter Application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sms

I am building a flutter app in which i want to capture incoming sms. I searched on pub.dev and found few packages offering similar functionality i.e. sms_maintained and sms_retreiver etc. I tried them but i am not satisfied with the provided functionality. I need more control such as listening to incoming sms messages while app is not running and manual control to start and stop listening for messages. So, i am thinking of writing own SMS handling code from scratch instead of using a package. I want guidance to achieve this. i.e. where to start???
I am new to flutter and mobile app dev, i don't know whether my question is worthy of being answered or not, that's why i am asking.

Comment: As you have tagged iOS, you should be aware that apps have no access to incoming text messages on iOS. Apps can send messages using `MFMessageComposeViewController` which gives the user a chance to edit or cancel the message before it is sent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are going in a big project by implementing a package like that. But there is no door a dev can't open :-)

There are some thing you should know before starting your project:

- Flutter is not able to do this by nature, **Flutter is an UI SDK**, every non-UI thing relay to the underlying platform (Android, iOS, Web, Desktop)
- Flutter is able to communicate with the native platform to do specific platform things (in your case, manage SMS)

You have to learn how to create a **native Flutter plugin**, a plugin implemented in platform-specific code (Java/Kotlin, Swift/Objective-c, C/C++/Go) which communicate with some Flutter UI code (written in Dart) via [Platform Channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

There are some tutorials found over the web:

- [Platform Channels, Benefits and Limitations](https://dzone.com/articles/platform-channel-in-flutter-benefits-and-limitatio)
- [Flutter Platform Channel](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-platform-channels-ce7f540a104e) (A pretty complete tutorial on Medium)
- [Method Channel In Flutter](https://fluttertutorial.in/method-channel-in-flutter/) (A simple one with example for Android platform)

Hope this will help, and good luck!